# Is "Monkey Runner" useful for testers to prepare test cases directly in Android applications?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, bug-tracking, monkeyrunner

I have gone through the "Monkey Runner" for the following link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html
It has so much Java code. I am not able to under stand the code to create test cases. Is it only for developers, or the testers to test the application thoroughly. Is there any other pattern for creating test cases through code? Can any one suggest me about the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at my MonkeyRunner code. Should be easier then Java. Change path to save file, and replace phone number. I had only 1 problem. Cant Hangup a call.

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
    '''
    Created on Apr 1, 2011

    @author: sj
    '''

    import sys

    # import the MonkeyRunners modules used by this program
    from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice, MonkeyImage







    def browse(d):
        d.broadcastIntent("http://www.google.com/", "ACTION_MAIN")
        #d.startActivity(component="com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity")

    def debug(device):
        print" package:%s" % device.getProperty('am.current.package')
        print" action:%s" % device.getProperty('am.current.action')
        print" comp.class:%s" % device.getProperty('am.current.comp.class')
        print" comp.package:%s" % device.getProperty('am.current.comp.package')
        print device.getProperty('display.width'), device.getProperty('display.height')

    def screenshot(d):
        MonkeyRunner.sleep(1.0)
        result = d.takeSnapshot()
        MonkeyRunner.sleep(1.0)
        result.writeToFile('/yourPath/device.png', 'png')  

    def call(d):

        d.startActivity(component="com.android.contacts/.TwelveKeyDialer")
        print "Start Activity"

        MonkeyRunner.sleep(1.0)

        d.type("+XXXXXXXX")

        # Call number.
        print "Call"
        d.touch(190, 800, 'DOWN_AND_UP');
        # not working device.press('KEYCODE_CALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')

        print "Wait 10 sec"

        MonkeyRunner.sleep(10.0)

        # HangUp Call
        #device.press('KEYCODE_ENDCALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')

        print "Hang Up"
        #x1 = 215
        #x2 = 230
        #y = 700
        #start = (x1,y)
        #end = (x2, y)
        #steps = 2
        #pause = 0.2
        #device.drag(start, end, pause, steps)

        d.startActivity(component="com.android.phone/.InCallScreen")
        #device.touch(230, 700, "DOWN");
        MonkeyRunner.sleep(1.0)
        #device.touch(230, 700, "UP");

        d.touch(230, 700, 'DOWN_AND_UP');
        #device.touch(270, 650, 'DOWN_AND_UP');


    def main():
        print "Start"

        # Connect to the current device returning the MonkeyDevice object
        device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

        #MonkeyRunner.alert("Starting Activity", "monkeyrunner", "OK")

        if not device:
            print "Couldn't get connection"
            sys.exit()

        print "Found device"

        #call(device)
        browse(device)
        debug(device)
        screenshot(device)


        device.press('KEYCODE_ENDCALL', 'DOWN_AND_UP')

        MonkeyRunner.sleep(10.0)




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have learned monkeyrunner via this small guide. 
http://antoine-merle.com/introduction-to-the-monkey-runner-tool-2/

You do not have to use java, but to start low on python. For the ide you can use pycharm, which will give you a better start when creating classes in python.

As of the code which @Boris_Ivanov showed, this is a good start, but I would delete the "MonkeyImage" - as you are not using it also pushing the test cases into different files would add to speed if required to use.

One thing to talk about:

```
    Connect to the current device returning the MonkeyDevice object
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    #MonkeyRunner.alert("Starting Activity", "monkeyrunner", "OK")
```

I am using something like this and it does work all the way:

```
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(60)
    if not device:
        raise Exception('Can not connect to device')
```

Best luck.